# Equivalences and isomorphisms of short exact sequences

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

In case it's necessary, I'm working in the category $\mathbf{Ab}$ of abelian groups. My question concerns what I find to be a strange way of viewing the elements of the Ext group $\mbox{Ext}(A,B)$ of the abelian groups $A$ and $B$. The statement of my question is at the end of this post but first two definitions and some notation.

A *morphism* $\varphi\colon E\rightarrow E'$ of short exact sequences $$E=0\rightarrow B\rightarrow G\rightarrow A\rightarrow 0$$ and $$E'=0\rightarrow B'\rightarrow G'\rightarrow A'\rightarrow 0$$ of abelian groups is a triple $\varphi=(b,g,a)$ of group homomorphisms $b\colon B\rightarrow B'$, $g\colon G\rightarrow G'$ and $a\colon A\rightarrow A'$ making the obvious diagram commute. So, $\varphi$ is an isomorphism precisely when $b, g$ and $a$ are isomorphisms.

We say that the SESs (short exact sequences) $E$ and $E'$ are *equivalent* if $B=B'$, $A=A'$ and there exists a SES morphism $(b,g,a)=\varphi\colon E\rightarrow E'$ with $b=\mbox{Id}_B$ and $a=\mbox{Id}_A$. By the short five-lemma, if $\varphi$ is an equivalence of SESs, then it is a SES isomorphism.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Equivalence_of_extensions) says that the classes of equivalent SESs with fixed $A$ and $B$ are in one to one correspondence with the elements of the Ext group $\mbox{Ext}(A,B)$. However, one would have guessed that it would be more natural to view the elements of $\mbox{Ext}(A,B)$ as classes of **isomorphic** SESs with $A$ and $B$ fixed. My question is, are these actually equivalent ways of viewing the elements of the Ext group?

More precisely, if $E$ and $E'$ are short exact sequences of abelian groups with $A=A'$ and $B=B'$, is it true that if $E$ is isomorphic to $E'$ then $E$ is equivalent to $E'$? (If this is true, does it then hold in any exact category?)

Comment: Just as a remark, two isomorphic short exact sequences will be equivalent iff there is an automorphism of $G$ that simultaneously extends $b$ and lifts $a$. It seems unlikely that this can be done in general but I don't have a counterexample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no.

Consider a prime number $p>2$  and set
$$
E: \quad 0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \overset{\cdot p}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \overset{\pi}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p \longrightarrow 0
$$

$$
E': \quad 0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \overset{\cdot p}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \overset{\cdot 2 \circ \pi}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p \longrightarrow 0.
$$
Here the map $\pi$ is the standard projection, and $\cdot 2 \circ \pi$ is the canonical projection followed by the group automorphism of multiplication by two on $\mathbb{Z}/p$.

There is an obvious isomorphism of SES's, however one can check there cannot exist an equivalence: let's use your notation for maps $b,g,a$ and suppose it is an equivalence. Since $g$ must be an isomorphism, it is either multiplication by -1 or the identity. However, since $b= id_{\mathbb{Z}}$, we find $g=id_{\mathbb{Z}}$ as well. But then we run into problems since the maps on the right will not commute.

There are way more extensions of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ up to equivalence then there are up to isomorphism, i believe to remember that there are $p$ of the first kind (the ones as above with $2$ being any number between 1 and $p-1$, plus the split extension) and only two of the second kind, but these numbers might be incorrect.

Please let me know if this was the answer you were looking for!

**First original answer, incorrect:**
Counterexamples are not hard to find. For example take two copies of the split exact sequence
$$
0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 0
$$
and all maps $b,g,a$ multiplication by $-1$. Clearly $A=A'$ and $B=B'$ and it is an isomorphism of SES, but not an equivalence.

In my homological algebra class, i had a similar remark; the teacher then decided to say *ultraisomorphism* for what you call equivalence. (He is quite funny and a great teacher, but that aside)

The philosophy is the following: Such a short exact sequence is called an *extension* of $C$ bt $A$ (or the other way around, everybody always forgets) and one is interested in the possible ways to build such an extension. Seeing the groups $A$ and $C$ as your fixed building blocks, it comes as no surprise that you do not want to change them in any way, not even by an isomorphism.

Comment: @Joachim: Thanks for the answer. As Miha says, this isn't quite what I'm looking for. A counter example would constitute two isomorphic SESs with $A=A'$, $B=B'$ but for which *no equivalence exists*.

Comment: Ah, i see.. I read "isomorphism" instead of isomorphic. I'll think about it.

Comment: Nitpick: you want $p > 3$, because you need $2 \neq -1$.

Comment: Fixed, thanks @Hurkyl!

Comment: Thanks. Your new answer is really simple.

Comment: @Hurkyl, i just realized that in fact the argument still holds even if $p=3$. Because the middle map is forced to be the identity anyway! Or am i wrong?

Comment: @DanielRust, you're welcome. It was actually given in the class i already mentioned, so it might be some sort of standard example.. Bet regards, Joachim.

Comment: ah right. I didn't look at the rest of the diagram when I thought about that

Answer (score 2):

I've been thinking about this same issue lately, and one thing that has clarified it is remembering that $\operatorname{Ext}(\bullet, \bullet)$ is a  bifunctor, like $\operatorname{Hom}(\bullet, \bullet)$. So if we had a map between short exact sequences which was the identity on $B$ but not on $A$, then that non-identity map (call it $\varphi$) on $A$ should in general induce a non-identity endomorphism $
\operatorname{Ext}(\varphi,B)$ on $\operatorname{Ext}(A,B)$.